# How can I force Windows to make a file lower-case only?

Tags: windows-7

I am having an issue when developing a WordPress plugin in Windows, and then uploading it to any server running Linux. Originally, the filename of the file was `Blue.png` and thus I changed it to `blue.png`. At first it wouldn't change (or it did but was still saying `Blue.png`), I switched folders and came back and it was `blue.png`.

Now when I upload this plugin to any server running Linux, it reads the filename as `Blue.png` so now my plugin cannot find that file and throws an error.

What can I do to force it to use `blue.png` as the filename?

Comment: Is there not a solution in your file uploading program? Often they come with a rename filtering option to let you do things like this. Failing that you could simply rename it using the program you're uploading with, e.g. issuing a MOVE command to rename it with FTP.

Comment: Well I am using Git, not sure if it has that feature but I will be looking into it. Git was reading the filename as `Blue.png` as well.

Comment: Yeah I'm not disputing Windows didn't rename it as you wanted but Git probably wouldn't make renaming it on the Linux machine and mirroring that back to Windows very intuitive. Renaming the file on the command line might yield better results?

Comment: Apparently it worked with Git, although I'm sure it would work the same using the regular command line commands. Basically just using the `mv` command.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Windows does treat filenames in apparently odd ways, and because it is case insensitive you can find that just trying to change the case of a filename can be problematical. Thing aren't help by the fact that, for example, if the filename is all upper case it will get displayed in initial case, which makes it difficult know what case the filename actually has.

The simplest solution is to either delete the file and recreate it or rename it to something completely different and then back to the name you actually want. So in your case you'd go:

> Blue.png -> green.png -> blue.png

If you are using source control then you'll have to perform this rename in your source control application rather than in Windows. In this case Windows is being told what the name is and you can't modify it.

Comment: Thanks, renaming it worked, although I had to use Git (`git mv Blue.png blah.png` then `git mv blah.png blue.png`). Windows didn't care what I was trying to do. :)

Comment: @Jared Ah - my mistake. That's true as well.